# Taylor's Formula and 'z' values

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have attached Taylor's Formula, an exercise problem from a section on Taylor polynomials, and the solution to this exercise.  I understand part a, expanding $f$ using Taylor polynomials is the simple part.

I am having trouble understanding what exactly is $z$ in Taylor's Formula.  I am also having trouble understanding why the value of $4$ is being plugged in for $z$.  Other exercises are similar, the lower bound is being plugged in for $z$ but in other problems, the upper bound is being plugged in.  Why are we plugging in a value for $z$?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: To see why we plug in a value, we can first think of what we're doing.  In (9), we're attempting to get something close to the square root of $x$, so we say $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.  Now, we would like to have something that works well for any value between 4 and 4.2, so we say $4 \le x \le 4.2$.  So when we substitute 4 for $x$ or $z$, we're actually trying to get an approximation for the square root of 4.  Of course the answer is 2, but what if we wanted the square root of something harder, like 4.123?  Then we can plug in 4.123 into the formulas.  $R_n(x)$ tells us how close this is.

Comment: If you'll forgive the self-promotion, I once wrote a [note on Taylor series](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1520) for my students. In short, the $z$ is coming from the mean value theorem. In general, you want to understand how bad the error can be, so you see how big the error *might* be by maximizing the $n$th derivative.

Comment: Why we do use Lagrange's form of the remainder when Taylor's Inequality is much more intuitive?